# Magento 1.9.1 Forgot Password issue

Tags: php, magento

We are facing a problem with a forgot password on domain.com/customer/account/forgotpassword.

When we enter any wrong email id not associate with any account its works we get this message:

> "If there is an account associated with test@test.com you will receive
>   an email with a link to reset your password."

But when we do with email id associate with account exist its show blank page on domain.com/customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/

I tried solution all side coustmer.xml file mail setting return path yes, but issue is same the same.

Comment: Check the account controller's forgotPasswordPostAction method

Comment: Formatting makes it easer for people to read and understand your question.  You may want to add some code.

Comment: @muk i checked it its remain same mean as old one we used..

dalmto thanks but no any custom code or else i m using

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an error breaking your code.

Please check your apache error logs for uncaught errors from Magento

as well as your

> root/var/exception.log

and

> root/var/system.log

If logs are not enabled, enable them in...

> admin/system_config/edit/section/dev/

Debug the following files:

> app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php

Use zend debug on: forgotPasswordPostAction line by line on variables such as:

```
Zend_Debug::dump( $customer );
Zend_Debug::dump( $newResetPasswordLinkToken );
```

> app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php
>   changeResetPasswordLinkToken
>
> app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php
>   sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail
>
> app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php
>   _sendEmailTemplate

```
Zend_Debug::dump( $mailer );
```

Dump out mailer contents on each line to pinpoint which call breaks your code.

As another alternative you can wrap the calls in a try{}catch( Exception $oException ){ Zend_Debug::dump( $oException); }

Comment: i got this error 

Call to a member function setMessageBody() on a non-object in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 410

Comment: line 406 place this and check what it returns: var_dump( $this->hasQueue() );
die;

Comment: its giving  "bool(false) "

Comment: Debug var_dump( get_class( $this ) ); to see if another module is overriding default Magento behavior.

Comment: got this Message.. 

bool(false) string(30) "Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template"

Comment: Check your apache logs for unhandled Magento errors. Apparently if Mage does not find a user everything works but if it does it breaks somewhere... likely in the mailer. Try to var_dump/zend_debug variables with a die; call at the end until you can trace it back to where your statement stops printing. Apache logs usually speed this needle search.

Comment: with         zend_debug( $this->hasQueue() ); die; 

its not print anything else and appache logs show this error
[21-Mar-2015 13:37:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function zend_debug() in /home/gem/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 406

Comment: I didn't have the spelling proper: Zend_Log::DEBUG is the function which does the same thing as var_dump but includes a stacktrace.

Comment: Zend_debug::dump() ; giving message NULL

Comment: You have to use in the dump out potentially problematic variables. Are your apache logs empty when you get the white screen error? Try to restart apache and monitor the error file if its enabled. The long route is going through the forgot password route... sec I'll edit answer with files to check.

Comment: after this its getting same message.. i used dump with text. its giving all email text i got the email in submit whole text .

.[21-Mar-2015 13:51:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setMessageBody() on a non-object in /home/gem/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 410

Comment: Since this appears to be a vanilla bug, the easiest way to fix it may be to try a new magento installation. Otherwise continue to debug why $emailQueue isn't a proper object. Check http://www.atwix.com/magento/debugging-hints/ for additional debugging methods.

Comment: Does it send out an email?

Comment: yess i removed the code of all if conditions and its sending the email